# Adding custom codec to rxjava vertx EventBus

Tags: java, rx-java, vert.x

I am using `vertx-rx-java`

I have two verticles which communicate which each other using EventBus, one of the verticles returns complex object as the result, to do so I created custom `MessageCodec` and wanted to register it in `EventBus`.

In standard `io.vertx.core.eventbus.EventBus` there is a method `registerCodec` which gives possibility to register custom codecs for this `EventBus`.

However since I am using `io.vertx.rxjava.core.Vertx`, by calling `vertx.eventBus()` I receive `io.vertx.rxjava.core.eventbus.EventBus`, which doesn't have such method. What is the purpose of removing this method from rxjava `EventBus`, is it considered bad practice to use custom codecs whens using rxjava? If so, what is the recommended approach?

The only way to add custom codec I found is to call `eventBus.getDelegate()`:

```
EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();

((io.vertx.core.eventbus.EventBus) eb.getDelegate()).registerCodec(new StringMessageCodec());
```

Comment: Caveat: I know next to nothing about Vertex/EventBus, but I can see that https://vertx.io/preview/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Vertx.html#eventBus-- returns https://vertx.io/preview/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.html which *does* have https://vertx.io/preview/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.html#registerCodec-io.vertx.core.eventbus.MessageCodec- . That contradicts your statements... Perhaps an upgrade would solve your problem?

Comment: @WillCain you are looking at the wrong class, this one is from vertx-core and I wrote that it works well, however I am using vertx-rxjava so if you take a look at `io.vertx.rxjava.core.Vertx` class it returns `io.vertx.rxjava.core.eventbus.EventBus ` which doesn't have such method.

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry, it looked like your question originally referenced io.vertx.core.eventbus.EventBus.

Comment: The good news is it looks like this has changed recently (August) on the master branch, see they removed @GenIgnore https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/commit/10d536a16c2abb3dda4c621d0ced4926f23c9224#diff-9756199aada8859558512fdd59449127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer appears it has not been supported. Hoewever this has changed recently (August) on the unreleased master branch; see they removed `@GenIgnore` from `EventBus` [here](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/commit/10d536a16c2abb3dda4c621d0ced4926f23c9224#diff-9756199aada8859558512fdd59449127). However, that is not yet in the release [3.5.3](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/3.5.3/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.java#L202). Presumably this change will go out in one of the next releases.

Comment: Vert.x uses code generation to create the Vert.x language APIs (Javascript, Ruby) and RxJava API. Some types were not supported  and thus generated APIs were missing a few methods. As Will pointed out, this will change in 3.6 (to be released in the next couple of months).